# Adicionar arquivos excluídos na hora de publicar ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

No meu projeto do Asp.Net Core tenho alguns arquivos excluídos do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando eu faço a publicação esses arquivos não aparecem na pasta wwwroot do projeto.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="wwwroot\Features\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToOutputDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

  <Content Include="wwwroot\Features\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <None Include="wwwroot\Features\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <!-- CopyToPublishDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Com este código eu tentei adicionar aqueles arquivos durante a publicação, mas não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Essa pasta não pode estar visível no projeto, mas deve ser publicada.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ou me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não entendi porque esses arquivos não podem ser visíveis... se eles não fazem parte da sua solução você não deveria realizar a sua publicação durante o publish do projeto...

Comment: Porque eu utilizo o padrão CQS onde esse arquivo Inserir.js fica dentro da pasta Features, e para não gerar dependência e ficar com os arquivos unificados eu fiz uma cópia usando o libman para dentro do wwwroot, dai só falta publicar.